# How to export a mysql table to a file

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, mysql-python

I got a large table with 97972561 rows. I would like to export the table into a file (txt or json or pickle or anything), which is easier for my following operations. How can I do it? I tried to query "select * from the_table" and save the result into a file, but it takes a long time and failed. I also have tried "into outfile", but my "secure_file_priv" is null and I cannot change it.

```py
mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
        host="localhost",
        user="username",
        passwd="xxxxxx",
        db="mydb")
        cur = mydb.cursor()

        query = "SELECT * FROM PREDICATION"
        cur.execute(query)

        all_recordings = cur.fetchall()
        mydb.close()

        # save all recordings to a pickle file
        with open('recordings.pkl', 'wb') as f:
            pickle.dump(all_recordings, f)
```

I am currently using mysql server 8.0.18 in terminal (Mac) and workbench 6.3. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Learn about `outfile` refer [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select-into.html)

Comment: I have tried it, but my "secure_file_priv" is null and I cannot solve it.

Comment: You should have mentioned that you tried out this and got an error. So that we can help adding extra details how to make it work.

Comment: Try adding `secure_file_priv` in the config file with a path. For this you need to restart the server. Refer [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_secure_file_priv) for more info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option here would be to use MySQL's `SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE` capability (but see below for notes):

```
query = """SELECT * FROM PREDICATION
INTO OUTFILE 'recordings.pkl'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'"""

cur.execute(query)
```

This is probably the fastest way to dump a MySQL table to CSV, and should be much faster than your suggested approach, which requires reading all the data into Python before writing it out.

Note that would generate a CSV file called `recordings.pkl` on the same machine where MySQL is running, *not* on the machine running your local Python script.  So, you would probably need an additional step here to move the CSV to the machine you want.  But, given that this approach avoids any roundtrips to/from the database, the cost of moving the file might be small compared to your current approach.

Comment: I have tried it, but my "secure_file_priv" is null and I cannot solve it.

Comment: MySQL simply cannot create a file in an arbitrary location!

Comment: @SalmanA The location isn't arbitrary at all, it would be relative to the location of MySQL.  I don't actually know where the OP wants to write.

Comment: I meant you need to whitelist a specific directory by setting `secure_file_priv` variable. MySQL cannot create files in arbitrary locations.

Comment: You should also specify about which OS (i.e. Windows or Linux) you are commenting.